# Retrieving random key from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Retrieveing random key]

How should I retrieve random key from Firebase realtime database that are stored in list?

Comment: its my first time in stack overflow.is my image available that i have uploaded with this question

Comment: DatabaseReference inspirationalTable= database.getReference("inspirational");

Comment: Yep, the image is visible but I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) answer guide line. In your answer you are missing your test code.

Comment: Kerberos,i will definitely add code next time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("inspirational");
   ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        String randomkey=dataSnapshot.getkey();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
      }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Use `ChildEventListener` since this is a list, first get the reference of the database. `.child("inspirational")` it means we are querying on that location.
Then inside `onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)` retrieve your data.